# I need a list of Frei0r DLL effects and the specifications for the parameters when using FFMPEG. Does anyone know of a list or source?

Tags: ffmpeg

I have looked all over for specifications on how to use the Frei0r DLL effects from the FFMPEG command line interface and have come up basically with a dry hole. Does anyone here know where I can find such a list of the DLL and the specifications on how to use them with FFMPEG CLI?

Answer (score 2):

Get the latest package of the compiled DLLs from the bottom of the page at http://oss.netfarm.it/mplayer/. Make sure you have set the environment variable `FREI0R_PATH` to point to the folder where you unzipped them.

Basic syntax is

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf frei0r=filtername:param1_value|param2_value|param3_value  output.mp4
```

The MLT site at https://www.mltframework.org/bin/view/MLT/PluginsFilters has details on the available parameters for *most* filters. Scroll down to see the entries beginning with `frei0r`.

Alternatively, get the corresponding source code from https://files.dyne.org/frei0r/. 
I prefer to unpack them in a subfolder in `FREI0R_PATH`. Or consult the source online at http://code.dyne.org/frei0r/tree/src. The source code of each filter will have code dealing with parsing the parameters near the top. You are looking for the `f0r_get_param_info` function. Not user-friendly, but there it is.